# How to deal with multiple samples at the same spatial coordinate when building a MaxEnt model?

Tags: maxent

I am trying to get my first MaxEnt model built. This is for a coastal ecosystem. Environmental predictor variables include bathymetric depth and surface and bottom measurements of salinity, temperature, and dissolved oxygen. I want to build this model in RStudio and am currently writing out my methods.

I have ~50 years worth of sampling data in my study area. Some sites were sampled just once, while other sites were repeatedly sampled through time and have accumulated many data records at the same coordinate.

Does anyone know if MaxEnt will accept a background sample where some sites have a single sample, while other sites have multiple samples?

I have not built anything yet in RStudio. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.